# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306’ with Docker and FastAPI and SQlalchemy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, fastapi

actually i’m develop API with:

- FastAPI
- MySQL
- Sqlalchemy

Actually i can’t connect sqlAlchemy with MySQL in container

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: x_api
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports: 
      - 80:80
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql+mysqlconnector://user_x:pass_xx@db:3306/x_db
    depends_on:
      - db
  
    volumes:
      - ./src:/apps/src
      # - type: bind
      #   source: ./src
      #   target: /apps/src
        
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: x_db
      MYSQL_USER: user_x
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass_xx
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass_xx
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

My Configuration for sqlalchemy connector

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

database_url = "mysql+mysqlconnector://user_x:pass_xx@db:3306/x_db"

ENGINE = create_engine(database_url, echo=True)

SESSION = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)

BASE = declarative_base()
```

I get this error after docker-compose up

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306'
```

Comment: Is there any more to the exception than that?  If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work then?

Comment: How are you connecting? `localhost` cannot be used, but instead the `ip` of the container

Comment: Make sure that your MySQL database container (db) is up and running before your application container (app) attempts to connect to it. Just to verify that please restart the mysql container and see

Comment: How can verify if my db container is running before my Application app, in fact, i Think that’s the problem, because i change database.py and works, but when load i get error previously mention